# IO thread error : 1595 (Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master)

Tags: replication, percona

Slave status :

```
           Last_IO_Errno: 1595
           Last_IO_Error: Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
```

from error log :

```
       [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel 'db12': Unexpected master's heartbeat data: heartbeat is not compatible with local info; the event's data: log_file_name toku10-bin.000063<D1> log_pos 97223067, Error_code: 1623
       [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel 'db12': Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master, Error_code: 1595
```

> I tried to restarting the slave_io thread for many times, still its same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to keep on start io_thread whenever it stopped manually, hope its bug from percona

I have simply written shell and scheduled the same for every 10mins to check if io_thread is not running , start slave io_thread for channel 'db12';. It's working as of now

Comment: Hi there. Did you manage to find more information regarding this issue?

Comment: unfortunately , this requirement is no longer in my environment.  Hope this might be fix from percona latest releases.

Comment: I have the same issue on the B master server after the master A was disk full -- in a "master A <-> master B" replication setup;
I freed the space on master A, and now status on master A good on all front however I can't find a way to start slave IO thread running on master B; it errors out with "1595: Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master"

Comment: Just run "start slave io_thread; " for every 10 mins (cron it) .